# IIS 7 , WebFarm and ARR module

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, appfabric, web-farm-framework

I'm configuring my servers to work with WebFarm and the ARR module . 
I'm looking ofr implementing a functionality to use the ARR for versioning purposes on my system. 
Example : 
- I have N clients connect my Wcf service hosted on my Farm servers . 
- Client connects the service via WsHttpBinding.
- Client user username / password authentication to use the service methods.

Username and password is the only way I can recognize which client I get in the server side . 
I want to control for example clients (1,5,8) to use the service on version 1 , and clients(2,3,4,6,7) to user the service with version 2.

Can I do it with ARR . I don't understand if there is an option to wire the username and password with the url rules.

I'm aware about the Wcf routing service , but I need a more generic control for routing , for example web sites and not only Wcf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARR uses Condition rules. I have not tested this myself, but you could try creating a rule on the field REMOTE_USER.

For a full list see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Hi , it gives the PC name the client connect from, but not the username it uses with the message security .

Comment: I would suggest that if you control the servers then you could have a module (or the App itself) that inserts a cookie and you could use that cookie to route to the right farm of servers using the conditions.